# SqlParameter not supplied when using Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommand

This is how I set up my command. It stops with the first parameter, UpdateType. This code is being updated from VB.NET 2008 version.

```vb
Dim db As New DB()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

'Put into an object, and use AddWithValue due to Parameters.Add being deprecated.
Dim UpdateType As String = "PARAMETERS"

If IsNewJob Then
  cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_AddJob"
Else
  cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_UpdateJob"
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UpdateType
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrigJobName", OrigJobName.ToString)
End If

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", CInt(Utils.GetLoggedInUserID))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", ProjectName.ToString)
```

Comment: `Add(String, Object)`  is deprecated, not `Add(String, SqlDbType)`. Use `Parameters.Add` for your `@UpdateType` parameter (and the others if they aren't being treated as objects). [SqlParameterCollection.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8). `AddWithValue` doesn't support supplying the datatype.

Comment: You also are not setting the CommandType to StoredProcedure. And you really should use a different prefix than sp_, or even better no prefix at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Let's make this MORE clear - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: One of your strings is probably nothing. If the db field allows null then use SqlString.Null when your strings are nothing.

Comment: what is `IsNewJob ` here, not defined.

Comment: Thanks  Sean Lange, I saw that also on another post.

Comment: Note `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UpdateType` vs `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateType", UpdateType)`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.Add` instead with the type and for `NVARCHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `VARBINARY` 
 with the length.  Here I show how to do the tings you have in the question, I made up lengths just for the example.  Using `AddWithValue` can have negative impact on SQL performance and other things.

Some information to help you can be found in many places including here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types

```
Dim db As New DB()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
Dim UpdateType As String = "PARAMETERS"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

If IsNewJob Then
  cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_AddJob"
Else
  cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_UpdateJob"
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = UpdateType
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrigJobName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = OrigJobName.ToString
End If
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Utils.GetLoggedInUserID)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = ProjectName.ToString
```

Comment: Note, I did not deal with the missing `IsNewJob`, made assumption there it exists

Comment: The default value for SQLParameter.Size is inferred to the Value size so if you have a long length value the buffer will be more. So if you have a defined size it can also be truncated if the value is more than size.

Comment: In the .Add(String, SqlDbType, Int, String) method the final string is the source column name. Your code passes no values at all.

Comment: @Mary You are right, I fixed that, I almost never use this form, mostly setting the parameter properties individually and not VB in a while.

Comment: This really should be broken into one method for `sp_MB_AddJob` and one for `sp_MB_UpdateJob`

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used so you can control that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using blocks take care of this for you. Note a single Using block is handling both the connection and the command.

The `.Add` method is NOT being deprecated. What is obsolute is the `.Add(String, Object)` overload. `.AddWithValue is certainly out of favor. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

I had to guess at the datatype and column size of your parameters. Check your database for the actual values and correct the code accordingly.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim UpdateType As String = "PARAMETERS"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        If IsNewJob Then
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_AddJob"
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_MB_UpdateJob"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = UpdateType
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrigJobName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = OrigJobName.ToString
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Utils.GetLoggedInUserID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = ProjectName.ToString
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```